# How can I align video right so that my text wraps around my vertical video?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, video

I have been trying to find a way to embed some video footage into a blog post and have it align to the right of the page and have text wrap around it.

This is what I have written so far to get the video to embed, but I can't see to figure out how to get it to align right.

This is the first time I have to look into the code part of my site as so much of it is very easy using Wordpress so this has stumped me a bit.

Ive tried using class="right" which I found after a few mins googling but no luck, so I thought It would be better come just come here to have to hopefully explained properly.

```
<span> Various text above this code </span>

<video width="270" height="480" controls>
      <source src="VIDEO URL" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

<span> Various text below this code </span>
```

This works as expected, the video embeds perfectly but then when I try to use any type of code which I found online to align it, it just doesn't work.

Comment: You did a good job of explaining the issue. However, I would recommend you to add some more detail of your video's surrounding code. Right now, you will most likely get  "Maybe this will work" type of answers.

Comment: It's basically just that. I've written it in the Wordpress 'text' editor so the code around it is just `<span> text blah blah blah </span>`.

Comment: Then please, add the spans to your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likely get the job done:

```
<video style="float:right" width="270" height="480" controls>
  <source src="VIDEO URL" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: you beauty! Thank you so much, can't believe I didn't find this prior :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy and simple solution:

```
video {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
p {text-align: justify;}
```

Live Demo:

```css
video {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<video width="270" height="480" controls>
  <source src="VIDEO URL" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32.</p>
<p>
  The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>

<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32.</p>
<p>
  The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
   <p>
  The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
   <p>
  The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
   <p>
  The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
   <p>
  The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
   <p>
  The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
   <p>
  The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
   <p>
  The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
   <p>
  The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
```

Let ME know if this works with you.